# Can't get rid of querystring generated by EF parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm new to MVC and EF and I am experimenting a bit with its functionaltiy. I have a problem with my URL. I have 3 entity classes generated from existing DB with the EF. Those properties get filled but I keep seeing them in my URL even though I changed my routing.

```
routes.MapRoute(
                null,
                "Article{articleID}",
                new { controller = "Article", action = "Article" }
                );
```

My URL looks like this :

http://localhost:3629/Article2?User=System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.User_4AC672CE1F2946F8B58690EA73EF956F43E30746526AD255691FA5ABFC32BBFF&BlogComments=System.Collections........

So everything after the /Article2 should be removed,
can anyone tell me what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

When you make your ActionLink, are you certain that you only send the ID as parameter, and not the entire Article instance?

Comment: your right, i send the whole model.The reason i do that, i got errors when sending for example (a.articleID) : The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'articleID' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult Article(Int32)' in 'Blog.WebUI.Controllers.ArticleController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameternaam: parameters

Comment: Try to remove your MapRoute configuration, change the parameter name of your Article-action to "id" and load /Article/Article/2

Comment: i cant get that far.As soon as i pass 'a.articleID' from my html.actionlink() instead of 'a'(full object from model) i get that error.When i do (long? id) as parameter in my actionmethod it works but the id is null for some reason.

Comment: I believe this is due to the MapRoute you defined, which is why I wanted you to remove that.